# How to extract a multiline text segment between two delimiters under a certain heading from a text file using C++

Tags: c++, search, text, ifstream

I have made a program that, based on user input, generates the following .txt word list:

> <>fauve:
>
> "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
>
> Definition of fauve:
>
> 1 : of or relating to painters practicing fauvism
>
> 2 : vivid in color
>
> Example 1 of fauve:
>
> "Fauve colors brought sizzle back to tableware, but could you really
> eat off a Rorschach of orange, black and pink?" - Julie V. Iovine, The
> New York Times Magazine, 14 Mar. 1993
>
> Example 2 of fauve:
>
> "Three were landscapes.. The other was a later painting of Adele, pale
> and strained, standing in a big hat with her arms loose amid fauve
> colours of red, mauve and green." - The Economist, 19 Feb. 2011
>
> Explanation of fauve:
>
> When French art critic Louis Vauxcelles spotted a statue reminiscent
> of 15th-century Italian art in the midst of works by an avant-garde
> group of painters-principal among them Henri Matisse-at an exhibit in
> Paris in 1905, he verbalized his shock with the words "Donatello au
> milieu des fauves!" ("Donatello among the wild animals!"). His
> reaction was to the painters' unconventional use of intensely vivid
> color and free treatment of form, and apparently his words weren't far
> off the mark in describing their art: Matisse and company's art
> movement became known as "Fauvism" and the artists flourishing in it,
> the "Fauves." In 1967, the intense impact of their colors was still
> vibrant, inspiring one writer for Vogue to use fauve as an adjective
> to describe the colors of a "striking" flowered coat-and that use can
> still be found today vivifying colors.
> ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

(PS: the quotation marks around the line of hyphens were added so it will display as in the text file. When pasting it in directly, it just made the headline bold. It is really just the word, then carriage return, then the line of hyphens, then two carriage returns before “Definition.”)

The program appends a new entry every time it is run except when the proposed entry already exists.

What I would like to do is to create another program that captures all the text between the line of hyphens and the line of underscores and displays it based on the user input “fauve.” Below is a rough sketch of said program, in which only the code required for assigning the delimiters and printing out the text segment is missing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string TextFile;
    cout << "Enter the wordlist to search:" << "\n";
    getline(cin, TextFile);

    string Search;
    int Offset = 0;
    string Line;
    ifstream iEnglishVocabulary;
    iEnglishVocabulary.open(TextFile + ".txt");

    string Word;
    int Dummy = 0;

    //Input

    cout << "Enter the word:" << endl;
    getline(cin, Word);

    Search = "<>" + Word + ":";
    if (iEnglishVocabulary.is_open())
    {
        while (!iEnglishVocabulary.eof())
        {
            getline(iEnglishVocabulary, Line);
            Offset = (Line.find(Search, 0));
            if (Offset != string::npos)
            {
                cout << THE ENTRY THAT FOLLOWS THE WORD ENTERED;                
            }
        }
    }        
    cin >> Dummy;  

    iEnglishVocabulary.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a programming question for us? Are you having trouble opening a file, reading it, processing it etc? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I'm sorry. I may have phrased it poorly. How can I extract the text between the line of hyphens and the line of underscores in the text file based on the user input “fauve,” and output the text in the terminal window.

Comment: Just a moment, I will upload my file so far and be more specific about what I want to achieve.

Comment: Wow! I have to say, if you can imagine writing a whole book on the subject of extracting a multi line text segment between two delimiters under a certain heading from a text file using C++ . . . you have one amazing imagination. I am very impressed. I certainly hope you are putting that amazing imagination of yours to good use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a closer look at reading text files in C++, I settled on this passable but most likely far from ideal solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string TextFile;
    cout << "Enter the wordlist to search:" << "\n";
    getline(cin, TextFile);

    string Search;
    int Offset = 0;
    int Offset2 = 0;
    string Line;
    ifstream iEnglishVocabulary;
    iEnglishVocabulary.open(TextFile + ".txt");

    string Word;
    string EntryEnd = "________________________________________";
    int Dummy = 0;
    bool PassingEntry = 0;
    bool WordFound = 0;

    //Input

    cout << "Enter the word:" << endl;
    getline(cin, Word);

    Search = "<>" + Word + ":";
    if (iEnglishVocabulary.is_open())
    {
        while (!iEnglishVocabulary.eof())
        {
            getline(iEnglishVocabulary, Line);
            Offset = (Line.find(Search, 0));
            Offset2 = (Line.find(EntryEnd, 0));
            if (Offset != string::npos)
            {
                PassingEntry = 1;
                WordFound = 1;
                cout << endl << endl;
            }
            if (PassingEntry == 1)
            {
                if (Offset2 != string::npos)
                {
                    PassingEntry = 0;
                    cout << Line << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << Line << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        if (WordFound == 0)
        {
            cout << "The word is not in the list" << endl;
        }
    }

    //Output

    cin >> Dummy;

    iEnglishVocabulary.close();

    return 0;
}
```

This solution does include the heading and bottom line also, as I found that worked better. If anyone has a better solution I’m sure posterity would be grateful.